# Generation of Selenium reports using Hudson (now known as Jenkins) from JUnit XML format file

Tags: testing, selenium, junit, hudson, automated-tests

For Test Automation of web project we use [Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29), [PHPUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit), and [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29). The results of the build are stored in the [JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) XML format.

When I try to include generation of reports using the Hudson **Publish JUnit test result report** option, the build finishes with **Failed** status.

Below is my Hudson configuration to run the tests.

```
sudo -u apache phpunit - log-junit /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Work-stars-Tests/builds/${BUILD_ID}/ seleniumReports/seleniumTests.xml + path to test php files
```

Generation of reports is enabled through the Hudson configuration option **«Publish JUnit test result report»**, where I specify the path to the folder with PHP tests.

The user we use to run Hudson has permission to write/read files in the folder with the reports. As for the path we've tried to specify both full and relative.

The error **No test report files were found. Configuration error?** is displayed in the console after the build.

How do we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found my own solution to this problem :)

In Hudson project configuration settings modified execute shell command to

```
> #!/bin/sh -x phpunit --log-junit ${WORKSPACE}/zf/tests/_tmp/reports/seleniumTests.xml
> ${WORKSPACE}/zf/tests/selenium/; sed
> -i '/<testsuite name=".*\/"/D;/^  <\/testsuite>$/D'
> ${WORKSPACE}/zf/tests/_tmp/reports/seleniumTests.xml
```

and set following path to Junit reports

> **/zf/tests/_tmp/reports/*.xml

Problem is solved. Yahoo!